# HTML5 & getUserMedia - Record Audio & Save to Web Server after Certain Time

Tags: php, html, audio, microphone, getusermedia

I'm having some difficulties with getUserMedia with HTML5 whilst developing my web page. This is the first time I've tried to implement this to record a users audio input. Flash is not an option for this project as it has to be used on mobile devices too.

I come here to see if anyone has experience with and knows how to implement an HTML5 with getUserMedia to record a users microphone for a certain amount of time (done with a session in PHP) and then saves and sends the audio file to a web server.

If this isn't possible then is there any other way, perhaps with a Java applet?

The js:

```
<script>
      var onFail = function(e) {
        console.log('Rejected!', e);
      };

      var onSuccess = function(s) {
        var context = new webkitAudioContext();
        var mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(s);
        recorder = new Recorder(mediaStreamSource);
        recorder.record();

        // audio loopback
        // mediaStreamSource.connect(context.destination);
      }

      window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      navigator.getUserMedia  = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

      var recorder;
      var audio = document.querySelector('audio');

      function startRecording() {
        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, onSuccess, onFail);
        } else {
          console.log('navigator.getUserMedia not present');
        }
      }

      function stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.exportWAV(function(s) {
          audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(s);
        });
      }
    </script>
```

The HTML (linked to recorder.js from [here](https://github.com/jwagener/recorder.js/)):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="recorder.js"> </script>

    <input onclick="startRecording()" type="button" value="start recording">
    <input onclick="stopRecording()" type="button" value="stop recording and play">
```

Comment: Do you have the code for what you've tried so far?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: @ robertc Edited question to show you the code I'm using.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### can use XMLHttpRequest

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload.aspx', true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
    };

    xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

// stop recording function calls the upload method
// I am using recorder.js

recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audio.src = url;
    audio.controls = true;
    var hf = document.createElement('a');
    hf.href = url;
    hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
    upload(blob);   
});

// on server side ASPX pageload - can save .wav file on server

Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/foo/" + "1" + ".wav"), false);
```

Comment: How to save a wav file on the server in PHP if it has been sent using XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Bit late to the party, but probably in mysql as a blob or varbinary should be sufficient.

Comment: @web_ninja Don't put a whole media file into a databse. Store the file as a file in the local filesystem (that's waht this system is for). And store only a link to the file in the mysql database.

Comment: In PHP you would do something like `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'], "destination.wav")`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305930/813988)