# Audio Recorind php and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, audio, audio-recording

i need audio recording for my running project.

Is someone know how i can record only voice and store as well?

Will be great if someone suggest some jQuery plugins are provide me code.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML5 to capture microphone and record voice:

```
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

A good starting point can be:
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
- Also check: [HTML5 & getUserMedia - Record Audio & Save to Web Server after Certain Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810450/html5-getusermedia-record-audio-save-to-web-server-after-certain-time)